# Connect the username when sending a report in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am beginner to django and I am trying to create a site to send reports after creating a profile, but when I send the report, the username of the author of the report is not saved, Just (None). I searched a lot about it and did not find it

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=("user"), null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    identity_No = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_No = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField( max_length=15,null=True)



class Meta:
    verbose_name =("Profile")
    verbose_name_plural =("Profile")

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' %(self.user)




class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=("user"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Report_type =models.CharField( max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    Region =models.CharField( max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    city =models.CharField( max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    sector =models.CharField( max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    report =models.TextField( max_length=3000, blank=True, null=True)
    files =models.FileField( blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name =("Report")
        verbose_name_plural =("Report")


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' %(self.user)
```

**form.py**
Shorten the time, attach only the report

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ['Report_type', 'Region', 'city','sector','report','files' ]
```

**view.py**

```
def report(requst):
    if requst.method == 'POST':
        report_form = ReportForm(requst.POST)
        if report_form.is_valid() :
            report_form.save()
            return redirect ('accounts:home')
    else:
        report_form = ReportForm()
    return render(requst, 'user/report.html', {
        'report_form': report_form,
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Vt3.png)  })

Comment: Is the user of the report the *logged in* user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link the new report wrapped in the `ReportForm` to the logged in user `request.user` with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def report(requst):
    if requst.method == 'POST':
        report_form = ReportForm(requst.POST)
        if report_form.is_valid():
            report_form.instance.user = request.user
            report_form.save()
            return redirect ('accounts:home')
    else:
        report_form = ReportForm()
    return render(requst, 'user/report.html', { 'report_form': report_form })
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).